# How to set background color to entire page in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 3.7.4.
I want to set background color to entire page.I didn't found any report property for background color.
Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can solve issue with help of `Background Band`.

I've put `staticText` element on `Background Band` and set ***`mode`*** attribute as *`Opaque`* and set the ***`backcolor`*** property.

The sample:

```xml
<jasperReport ... pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="595" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="338"/>
    <queryString language="xPath">
        <![CDATA[/Northwind/Customers]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="CustomerID" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CustomerID]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="CompanyName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[CompanyName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ContactName" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContactName]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ContactTitle" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[ContactTitle]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Address" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Address]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="City" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[City]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="PostalCode" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[PostalCode]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Country" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Country]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Phone" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Phone]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="Fax" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Fax]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band height="842" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="595" height="842" backcolor="#CCFFCC"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="128" y="29" width="298" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[The report with the background color]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="19" y="0" width="147" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{CompanyName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="166" y="0" width="260" height="20"/>
                <box leftPadding="10"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{City}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

The height of the `Background Band` should be equal to the whole report's height and the "transparent" `staticText` element must occupy the entire space of this band.

The result will be: 
[image: report with background color]

Comment: helped me to create a report with background image. Thanks for this!