# JasperReports Server: Background color for the screen on which the reports are displayed

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

How to change the background color for the whole screen (window) on which the report is displayed at *JasperReports Server* rather than changing the background color for the report with *JasperReports*?

Comment: See this post :
[Same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399684/how-to-set-background-color-to-entire-page-in-ireport) This topic use Ireport

Comment: @Aroniaina in the question you specified it adds a background color according to the report height and width but my question is to add background for the whole window in which the report is displayed.

Comment: @Aroniaina What about changing the CSS file in Jasper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For changing the color of the `Entire Window` you can edit the `CSS` file in the `jasperserver/themes` like this

```
#reportViewFrame .content .body{
        background:#f6f6f6; //any color you want
}

.jrPage > tbody {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #f6f6f6; // any color you want
}
```

Comment: Let me see.. I will let you know.